# Нужна помощь с асинхронной функцией

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, express

Очень нужно переделать данную функцию с использованием Async / await, буду очень благодарна за помощь
/////////

```js
app.put('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    var db = req.db;
    Post.findById(req.params.id, 'title description', function (error, post) {
        if (error) { console.error(error); }

        post.title = req.body.title
        post.description = req.body.description
        post.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            res.send({
                success: true
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу несколько проблем в вашем коде.

1. Вы где-то выше подключаете БД и шарите  её в объекте request. Это не верный подход, в своё время мне разработчики express отвечали также. Нужно использовать пулл коннектов.
2. Вы не обрабатываете ошибки из бд, а продолжаете работать с ответом. Ошибки нужно обрабатывать в своём обработчике, а передавать с помощью `next`.
3. Вы используете expressм v4, который явным образом не заточен под промисы.

Самый простой способ подключить async / await в express это использование [async-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-middleware). Он сам ловит все catch от промисов и кидает их в обработчик ошибок. Теперь вы можете безопасно писать что-то вроде

```
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id, 'title description')
```